# Why are .deb files used in iOS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, unix

If you jailbreak in iOS, you can install packages using .deb files. Being a Linux user I know Debian-based distros use that file type for apt. I know that iOS is not Debian-based or Linux-based, but it is UNIX-based. Why does iOS use .deb files when you jailbreak?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you explain in more detail what files specifically are .deb? "you install stuff" is quite broad - It could be that some developers are using them "for reasons" and since we're not about software development, this needs to be about a practical problem you are solving and not a "how come people Y did Z?". (just edit the post with the added detail and the hold can be reviewed)

Comment: It's the cydia installer that uses dpkg in the installation process : saurik explains really well on his blog : http://www.saurik.com/id/7 + http://www.saurik.com/id/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jay Freeman ("saurik")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Freeman) is the developer of Cydia and brought Debian APT to iOS.

> The iPhone … is running a pared down Mac OS X with its standard complement of a FreeBSD-based userland over a Darwin kernel.

> For distribution, I have chosen Debian's APT

<sup>Source: http://www.saurik.com/id/1</sup>

These elements together delineate .deb files as the container for the package to be installed.

> In the world of Debian APT/dpkg, anything you can install is a "package". These packages exist in the form of .deb files

<sup>Source: http://www.saurik.com/id/7</sup>

dpkg-deb allows these deb files to be installed and managed easily and with little overhead, which is very important for iOS devices.